# Is it possible to conduct ANOVA on paired samples?

Tags: anova, paired-comparisons, paired-data

I have data similar to that (fake values):

```
| Individual | Profession  | Software_A | Software_B |
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|
| A          | Teacher     |        4.5 |        3.2 |
| B          | Cop         |        5.0 |        2.0 |
| C          | Teacher     |        2.0 |        1.2 |
| D          | Cop         |        5.0 |        2.0 |
| E          | Hairstylist |        1.0 |        0.5 |
```

Need to test if mean rates of **`Software_A`** is greater than **`Software_B`** for some **`Professions`**.

I can conduct a Paired Sample T-test comparing means, but that would give me the overall difference, not within groups.

Is there something like a Paired Sample ANOVA?

## Possible solutions

1. Should I simply compute a new variable called **`Rate_Difference = Software_A - Software_B`** and conduct ANOVA with **`Profession`**?

```
| Individual | Profession  | Software_A | Software_B | Rate_Difference |
|------------|-------------|------------|------------|-----------------|
| A          | Teacher     |        4.5 |        3.2 |             1.3 |
| B          | Cop         |        5.0 |        2.0 |               3 |
| C          | Teacher     |        2.0 |        1.2 |             0.8 |
| D          | Cop         |        5.0 |        2.0 |             0.5 |
| E          | Hairstylist |        1.0 |        0.5 |             0.5 |
```

2. Should I restructure data turning **`Software_A`** and **`Software_B`** into different cases and perform a Bivariate ANOVA on **`Rate`** versus **`Software`**  versus **`Profession`**?

```
| Individual | Profession  | Software | Rate |
|------------|-------------|----------|------|
| A          | Teacher     | A        |  4.5 |
| B          | Cop         | A        |  5.0 |
| C          | Teacher     | A        |  2.0 |
| D          | Cop         | A        |  5.0 |
| E          | Hairstylist | A        |  1.0 |
| A          | Teacher     | B        |  3.2 |
| B          | Cop         | B        |  2.0 |
| C          | Teacher     | B        |  1.2 |
| D          | Cop         | B        |  2.0 |
| E          | Hairstylist | B        |  0.5 |
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless there's something that I'm missing here, what you're looking to do is just to carry out a two-way [repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design#Repeated_measures_ANOVA). This will allow you to test whether software interacts with profession (i.e. does the effect of software vary from one profession to another).

You would need to ensure that each profession occurs a reasonable number of times in your data though. Maybe >5.

Comment: If he couldn't repeatedly measure, but instead just had a lot (*lot*) more data, how would he proceed?

Comment: @user2305193 two-way independent measures ANOVA